# Python global variable within map task isn't incrementing in global scope

Tags: python

Below I have a self-contained Python example demonstrating a thread pool. Each of the three thread calls the function `task()`.

I have a global variable. `task()` should increment `created` three times. However, `created` is always 1, instead of 1, 2, 3.

Could someone please help?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import operator
import time
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import threading
from functools import partial

global created

lock = threading.Lock()

def task(lock, ignore_arg):
   
    print("task")
    
    global created

    lock.acquire()

    # PROBLEM: this isn't incrementing globally
    created = created + 1

    # Always 1, instead of 1, 2 then 3
    print("created (" + str(created) + ")")
    lock.release()

def task_init(output_queue):
    task.output_queue = output_queue

if __name__ == '__main__':

    created = 0

    output_queue = mp.Queue()
   
    p = mp.Pool(3, task_init, [output_queue])

    manager = mp.Manager()
    lock = manager.Lock()

    func = partial(task, lock)
    
    list_of_inputs = ['2', '3', '4']

    p.map(func, list_of_inputs)
    
    p.close()
```

Comment: You're running each call to `task()` in a separate process.  Each one has its own entirely separate set of global variables, there's no connection between the processes at all.  Using threading instead of multiprocessing would be one possible fix, as then all the calls are running in the same process.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, you'll have to excuse me as i'm a C++ guy. Is there any way I can 'pass' my global variable in to task? Erguh, if they are separate processes then they'll never see each other even if i do pass it.....

Comment: @jasonharper The reason I want the global variable is I want all the calls to task to wait until each one is ready and I was using the global counter as synchronization.

Comment: @intrigued_66: That's what the shared memory types in the `multiprocessing` docs handle. Read more there.

Comment: If you wanted each process to have a distinct value, you'd need to pass it as a parameter.  You're basically doing that already with `ignore_arg`.  But if you want each call to wait until the previous one has finished, then why are you using multiprocessing/threading at all?   Just call them sequentially in the main program.

Comment: Sounds like you want [multiprocessing.Barrier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier). But make sure to pass it into the tasks from the parent process, instead of creating it at module scope.

Comment: @jasonharper The real `task()` has two steps. The first takes a random amount of time. I want all the tasks to complete their first step and then they begin the second step at exactly the same time.

Comment: @yurikilochek That has worked! Please put it as an answer and I will accept. Was very simple to implement

Comment: @intrigued_66 feel free to answer your own question with what worked for you!

Comment: @yurikilochek, an excellent and generous final comment.  upvote to you.